# String replacement with potential parentheses in the string

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

Let say I have a var `$text`:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. John Doe Ut tincidunt, elit ut sodales
>   molestie.

and a var `$name`:

> John Doe

I need to found out all occurrences of `$name` in `$text` and add an href around it. 
Which I currently do with `str_replace`.
But what if there is parentheses in the name?
Let say var `$text` look like this instead:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. John (Doe) Ut tincidunt, elit ut sodales
>   molestie.

or

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. (John) Doe Ut tincidunt, elit ut sodales
>   molestie.

How can I still found `$name` with thoses parentheses?

Comment: is parentheses the only possible variation?

Comment: You could use a regex but first you'd have to define the exact requirements, what kind of parenthesis, etc.

Comment: @Dagon parentheses are the only possible variation.

Comment: @jeroen the type of parenthesis will be exactly as provided in the example. Nothing else will be allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. (John) Doe Ut tincidunt, elit ut sodales molestie.";

$name = "John Doe";

function createUrl($matches) {
    $name = $matches[0];
    $url = str_replace(['(', ')'], '', $matches[0]);
    return "<a href='index.php?name={$url}'>{$name}</a>";
}
$pattern = str_replace(' ', '\)? \(?', $name);
echo preg_replace_callback("/(\(?$pattern\)?)/", 'createUrl', $text);
```

Answer (score 2):

split the name by first and last name.

```
$split = explode(' ', $name);
$first = $split[0];
$last  = $split[1];


preg_replace(
  "/(\(?($first)\)? \(?($last)\))/"
, $replacement
, $text
);
```

a more dynamic approach

```
// split name string into sub-names
$split = explode(' ', $name);

// initiate the search string 
$search = '';

// loop thru each name
// solves the multiple last or middle name problem     
foreach ($split as $name) {
  // build the search regexp for each name
  $search .= " \(?$name\)?";
}

// remove first space character
$search = substr($search, 1);

// preg_replace() returns the string after its replaced
// note: $replacement isn't defined, left it for you :)

// note: the replacement will be lost if you don't
//  print/echo/return/assign this statement.
preg_replace(
  "/($search)/"
, $replacement
, $text
);
```

Comment: I think you mean `preg_replace`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not split the name, because someone could be named for exemple: "Ryan Nugent Hopkins"

Comment: well then you can put the search string in a foreach loop to make it more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

another version that use just preg_split

```
$split=preg_split('/\s+/', $name);
$frst=$split[0];
$mid=$split[1];
$lst=$split[2];
```

another posibility is using ucwords

```
$split=ucwords($name);
$frst=$split[0];
$mid=$split[1];
$lst=$split[2];
```

and then

```
preg_replace('.?$frst.? .?$mid.? .?$lst.?',$replacement,$text);
```

works also with other type of delimiters [{()}] etc ...